# Same randomly generated integer repeats in while loop in c#

Tags: c#, random

I'm creating a text-based game, and in the game when an enemy hits you, the amount of damage done is randomly generated, however, in a while loop it repeats the generated number.

Expected Outcome

```
Okay, lets fight him!
The monster has a health of 25! What do you wish to do?
[Press 0 to attack.]
0
The monster's health went down by 2. Their health is now 23
The monster attacks! Your health went down by 9. Your health is now 41
The monster has a health of 23! What do you wish to do?
[Press 0 to attack.]
0
The monster's health went down by 2. Their health is now 21
The monster attacks! Your health went down by 10. Your health is now 31
The monster has a health of 21! What do you wish to do?
[Press 0 to attack.]
```

Output

```
Okay, lets fight him!
The monster has a health of 25! What do you wish to do?
[Press 0 to attack.]
0
The monster's health went down by 2. Their health is now 23
The monster attacks! Your health went down by 3. Your health is now 47
The monster has a health of 23! What do you wish to do?
[Press 0 to attack.]
0
The monster's health went down by 2. Their health is now 21
The monster attacks! Your health went down by 3. Your health is now 44
The monster has a health of 21! What do you wish to do?
[Press 0 to attack.]
```

You can see that in the output the amount of damage the enemy does is repeated. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Code:

```cs
using System;
using Game;

public class Zero
{
    public static void G1()
    {

        while (Player.HP > 0&&Enemy.h > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The monster has a health of {Enemy.h}! What do you wish to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("[Press 0 to attack.]");
            string read_action = Console.ReadLine();
            if (read_action == "0")
            {
                Enemy.h = Enemy.h - Player.At;
                Player.HP = Player.HP - Enemy.at;
                Console.WriteLine($"The monster's health went down by {Player.At}. Their health is now {Enemy.h}");
                Console.WriteLine($"The monster attacks! Your health went down by {Enemy.at}. Your health is now {Player.HP}");

            }
        }



    }
}
```

Variables that were in another file:

```cs
 public static Random numGen = new Random();
 public static int at = numGen.Next(1, 11); //this is the enemy's attack function
```

Comment: `at` is static and only initialized once

Comment: Note `Random` is correct to be static

Comment: I realized that and changed it. Ill edit the post

Answer (score 4):

The static „at“ variable is only evaluated once, meaning it is assigned a random value once and then never changed again.

Can you give more context about where this variable resides? You might want to move it into another class and don’t use a static variable, but a calculated property instead.

**Edit:**

Based on your clarifications, I think you could use a method or calculated property in the actual Enemy class. Here an example with calculated property:

```
public class Enemy {
   Random numGen = new Random();
   int minAttack = 1;
   int maxAttack = 11;

   public int Attack => numGen.Next(minAttack, maxAttack);
}
```

The Attack property of the enemy instance will be reevaluated on each access.

Comment: The variable is in another cs file where all the classes are for the program, in order to keep things organized. Should I put the "at" variable in the cs file shown here?

Answer (score 1):

The `at` variable is being initialised with the return value of the `.Next(1, 11)` function so if it returns 8 it will store the value 8 and keep that value.

You could get rid of the `at` variable and use this line instead to get a random number direct from the `numGen` variable.

```
Player.HP = Player.HP - Enemy.numGen.Next(1, 11);
```

Or you could write a function to handle getting a new attack value and storing it in the `at` variable, for example:

```
public int GetEnemyAttack()
{
    at = numGen.Next(1, 11);
    return at;
}
```

and then call it from the line where you're calculating the players new HP

```
Player.HP = Player.HP - Enemy.GetEnemyAttack();
```

Comment: In C#, method names should be PascalCase, and generally should involve a verb. Following that, something like `GetEnemyAttack` would be a better method name.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann! You're quite right. I've updated the answer with the corrected method name.